# async callback by define a certain parameter to function like jasmine in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

In jasmine, we use a callback function to test async action like this:

```
it(done => {
  // ...
})
```

How can we implement `it` this action logic? For example, I want to use a function like this:

```
call(id => {
  return id
})

call((id, done) => {
  setTimeout(() => done(id), 1000)
})
```

If there is a `done` parameter, the function will callback only when `done` is called.

Could anyone can help to implement this logic?

Comment: @Ty Semicolons are optional in Javascript. My linter underlines semicolons in red and says "Unnecessary semicolon".

Comment: Better use promises and decide on the type of the return value, than relying on a [function's arity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

Comment: ajax requests are async by nature. So, are you just trying to put something on the queue or are you waiting for a request to return or something similar? It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi ! It works.